# How to reduce spacing before each section in latex

Tags: cv

Below is my latex code. I have also uploaded a screenshot. As you can see from the screenshot that I want to reduce the space before the section title. I found some solution but they change the section title style. I want to keep this style but just need to reduce the space before the section.

```
%\title{My two column CV}
%
% tccv (two columns curriculum vitae) is a LaTeX class inspired by
% the template found at latextemplates.com by Alessandro Plasmati.
%
% Create by Nicola Fontana, the original files can be downloaded from:
% http://dev.entidi.com/p/tccv/
%
\documentclass{tccv}
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{MnSymbol}%
\usepackage{wasysym}%
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\begin{document}

\part{Md name}

\section{Software skills}

\begin{eventlist}
\textbf{Good level: } Ruby, Ruby on Rails, Active Record, MySQL, C, C++, HTML5, CSS3, Jquery, handlebars.js, Jquery UI, Twitter Bootstrap, Git, Github, Linux, Windows, Apache, MS Visual Studio 2012 \& 2008, Net-beans, RubyMine, Pivotal Tracker
\newline \newline
\textbf{Intermediate: } Backtrack 5, Latex, Wordpress
\newline \newline
\textbf{Basic level: } Java, C\#, PHP, Oracle 10g, AutoCAD 2007, MATLAB 7.0

\end{eventlist}

\section{Achievements}
\begin{itemize}
\item 4 years govt. scholarship for HSC result. 
\item 2 years govt. scholarship for SSC result. 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know that class, but perhaps a simple `raggedbottom` directive in the preamble would do the trick.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: `eventlist` inserts a `\bigskip` at the end. If you add some text after `\end{eventlist}` it should look OK. Otherwise you have to redefine `eventlist` to remove `\bigskip` at the end. This affects all `eventlist`s though.

Comment: @HarishKumar Do you want to make that an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Added the answer. Thanks for digging it up :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to reduce the space after all `eventlist` environments, put this in your preamble:

```
%% this will reduce space after all event lists.
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AfterEndEnvironment{eventlist}{\vspace{-1.5\baselineskip}}
```

On the other hand, if you want to do it after only some (or one) environment, add `\vspace{-1.5\baselineskip}` after `\end{eventlist}`:

```
\end{eventlist}
%\vspace{-1.5\baselineskip}
```

Here is the full code:

```
%\title{My two column CV}
%
% tccv (two columns curriculum vitae) is a LaTeX class inspired by
% the template found at latextemplates.com by Alessandro Plasmati.
%
% Create by Nicola Fontana, the original files can be downloaded from:
% http://dev.entidi.com/p/tccv/
%
\documentclass{tccv}
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{MnSymbol}%
\usepackage{wasysym}%
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%% this will reduce space after all event lists.
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AfterEndEnvironment{eventlist}{\vspace{-1.5\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\part{Md name}

\section{Software skills}

\begin{eventlist}
\textbf{Good level: } Ruby, Ruby on Rails, Active Record, MySQL, C, C++, HTML5, CSS3, Jquery, handlebars.js, Jquery UI, Twitter Bootstrap, Git, Github, Linux, Windows, Apache, MS Visual Studio 2012 \& 2008, Net-beans, RubyMine, Pivotal Tracker
\newline \newline
\textbf{Intermediate: } Backtrack 5, Latex, Wordpress
\newline \newline
\textbf{Basic level: } Java, C\#, PHP, Oracle 10g, AutoCAD 2007, MATLAB 7.0

\end{eventlist}
%\vspace{-1.5\baselineskip}  %% Do this if you want to reduce space only for one instance

\section{Achievements}
\begin{itemize}
\item 4 years govt. scholarship for HSC result.
\item 2 years govt. scholarship for SSC result.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

You can also patch the environment in the following way to remove the `\bigskip` inserted by the `eventlist` environment.

```
\renewenvironment{eventlist}{%
    \newcommand*\inskip{}
    \renewcommand\item[3]{%
    \inskip%
    {\raggedleft\textsc{##1}\\[1pt]}
    \ifstrempty{##2}{}{##2\\[2pt]}
    {\Large\textit{##3}}
    \medskip
    \renewcommand\inskip{\bigskip}}}
    {\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}}    %%< here you change, originally {\bigskip}.
```

Code again:

```
%\title{My two column CV}
%
% tccv (two columns curriculum vitae) is a LaTeX class inspired by
% the template found at latextemplates.com by Alessandro Plasmati.
%
% Create by Nicola Fontana, the original files can be downloaded from:
% http://dev.entidi.com/p/tccv/
%
\documentclass{tccv}
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{MnSymbol}%
\usepackage{wasysym}%
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\renewenvironment{eventlist}{%
    \newcommand*\inskip{}
    \renewcommand\item[3]{%
    \inskip%
    {\raggedleft\textsc{##1}\\[1pt]}
    \ifstrempty{##2}{}{##2\\[2pt]}
    {\Large\textit{##3}}
    \medskip
    \renewcommand\inskip{\bigskip}}}
    {\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}}    %%< here you change, originally {\bigskip}.

\begin{document}

\part{Md name}

\section{Software skills}

\begin{eventlist}
\textbf{Good level: } Ruby, Ruby on Rails, Active Record, MySQL, C, C++, HTML5, CSS3, Jquery, handlebars.js, Jquery UI, Twitter Bootstrap, Git, Github, Linux, Windows, Apache, MS Visual Studio 2012 \& 2008, Net-beans, RubyMine, Pivotal Tracker
\newline \newline
\textbf{Intermediate: } Backtrack 5, Latex, Wordpress
\newline \newline
\textbf{Basic level: } Java, C\#, PHP, Oracle 10g, AutoCAD 2007, MATLAB 7.0

\end{eventlist}

\section{Achievements}
\begin{itemize}
\item 4 years govt. scholarship for HSC result.
\item 2 years govt. scholarship for SSC result.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]